# wglCreateContextAttribsARB not defined?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

C++ application, I define a temp context, make it current, and then try to use wglCreateContextAttribsARB, which is simply undefined. Most answers I have seen say to use PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC. Which is also undefined. What am I missing?

I'm only using gl.h (provided by VS2015)

```
    SetPixelFormat(g_hDc, chosenPixelFormat, &pfd);
    HGLRC temporaryContext = wglCreateContext(g_hDc);
    wglMakeCurrent(g_hDc, temporaryContext);
    PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC wglCreateContextAttribsARB...
```

Both, however, are just unidentified. I initially tried calling wglCreateContextAttribsARB by itself, to no avail, anywhere in my code.

At this stage, I have a context working, windowed, 480p, updating, stable 60FPS. So I know my side is working. I'm getting no GL errors either. Where do I need to instantiate these two? Am I using the wrong gl header?

I'm using an updated ASUS Radeon R9-285

Comment: Feel free to use my tiny wglarb.h library: https://github.com/datenwolf/wglarb – also takes proper care about multithreading reentrancy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All data types and constants related to wgl extensions are declared in [`wglext.h`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/api/GL/wglext.h).

You need to query the function pointer of type `PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC` using your current context via the GL extension mechansim (e.g. [`wglGetProcAddress()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374386%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: Any further explanation? I cannot find an example proper.

Comment: So seems like you have marked this as answered. Could you please share the details @Aethedigm